# VBA print/export/save all Excel workbook tabs into one PDF document

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'M trying to print/export or save all my tabs in an excel workbook as one PDF document.

The number of tabs could be any number and could be named anything.

I have the following piece of code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\tempo.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

But this obviously requires the number of sheets and the exact names of the sheets. Is there a way to maybe count the number of sheets in a workbook and print all of these to PDF as one PDF doc?

Please can someone show me how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Simply use ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat or [ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx)*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()

    ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                     Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                     FileName:="C:\tempo.pdf", _
                     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                     IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                     OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

*[Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx)*